# pytorch: Does variable.long() guarantee 64-bits?

Tags: type-conversion, pytorch, tensor

In pytorch, I have a variable that might be `IntTensor` or `cuda.IntTensor`. It needs to be changed to 64-bits retaining cpu/gpu. Does `variable.long()` guarantee 64-bits on all implementations of pytorch? If not, how can variable be converted to 64-bits retaining cpu/gpu for all implementations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PyTorch documentation [here](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html), `torch.LongTensor` or `torch.cuda.LongTensor` can be used to ensure a 64-bit signed integer.

Similarly, for 64-bit floating points, you can use `torch.DoubleTensor` or `torch.cuda.DoubleTensor`.

You can convert them into variables by using `Variable(tensor)` method where `tensor` represents the tensor created above.